Looking for canonical answer along the lines of "Bitcoin mining is ASIC only at this point"
For the list of canonical questions I started yesterday, I am looking for a good (or the best) answer that could be a duplicate master for "Is it worth mining with Home PC/Laptop/Tablet/[anything not an ASIC]?".
Does anyone have a good suggestion?

The title says you're looking for a question, but your question says your looking "for a good answer". Are you looking for both?

@StephenM347: Well, I'd like the question to be sufficiently related to the topic and the answer exhaustively covering the topic. So, I guess I'm looking for a question/answer pair.

okay. I think an answer comparing the rough power efficiencies for different sets of hardware would be a good answer here, showing just how many orders of magnitude more efficient ASICs are than regular computers. This thread and the image on the thread may serve as a good starting point.

A comparison of efficiency would certainly be nice. I've read that KnCMiner has announced their 3D 16nm ASICs reaching 0.07W/GH per s. I don't think we have an answer here along the lines yet, though.

// , Such a sad subject.

I created my own answer and would appreciate suggestions what I could still improve:
In the ASIC-age, is it even worth starting casual mining at home?
